# How do I integrate Nutch and Solr to work with Drupal?

Tags: drupal, solr, integration, nutch

I configured my Drupal website to work with a Solr instance (using Apache Solr search inegration module) in order to have a better search than the one given by Drupal. In addition, I want my website to find results from many other websites when performing a search, and for that reason I configured a Nutch instance to work with the Solr instance (I mentioned above). 
Now, I can see data that was indexed by Drupal and data that was indexed by Nutch through my Solr instance interface. The problem is, though, that I can't see any data that was indexed by Nutch when performing a search in my Drupal website.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Drupal 7 the [Sarnia Module](http://drupal.org/project/sarnia) + [Search API](http://drupal.org/project/search_api) + [Search API Solr](http://drupal.org/project/search_api_solr) will allow you to search and present data from any Solr index (using Views). Search API is an alternative to the Apache Solr Search Integration module.